# When reviewing, I see numerous tag description filling, do I approve their creation when I approve the content?

Tags: discussion, review

My question is motivated by the fact that some tags whose filling is visible in the `review`page seem (to me) totally superfluous.

So, even if I agree with the description, I don't want to endorse the tag creation.

What's the exact result of my approval of the "edit" ? Is there a place to discuss/validate the tag creations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the tag wiki content to be suggested the tag has to exist in the first place.

So by approving the edit you're not approving the creation of the tag.

However, if you don't think the tag is a good tag, reject the edit and start retagging the questions that use it. If there are more questions than you think you can handle raise a question here on meta asking for help in the effort.

Answer (score 1):

a *review* edit is no different than a *normal* edit, and the consequences are the same, hence, no tags will be created simply by confirming the edit (tag creation also prompts the user to notify on this action).

further more, if one's reputation points don't allow for tag creation (the floor score for gaining that privilege on stackoverflow is 1500 points), they won't be able to create them regardless.

another thing - to create a new tag, it must have a "hosting" question that corresponds to the topic, so editing an answer, again, won't have any affect on that.

Comment: I have more than 1500 points in SO. So I will worry as much as I want :)

Comment: oh, i mixed your rep score here with the SO rep, editing my answer.